# Defining center of mass in the presence of curvature

Tags: curvature, definition

The definition of center of mass in most text books will look something like $\frac{\sum m_k r_k}{\sum m_k}$ or in the continuous case, $\frac{1}{\int \rho(r) dr}\int \rho(r) r dr$. However, this definition depends critically on some unspoken assumptions. At the very least, it seems that you must be working in a [normal coordinate chart](http://planetmath.org/riemannnormalcoordinates).

For instance, the above definitions fail badly if we decide to work in polar coordinates: If $(R, \theta_k)$ are the polar coordinates of $n$ points spaced evenly around a circle, we should expect their center of mass to be at $(0, 0)$. However, with the definitions, we get that the center of mass will be at some point with coordinates $(R, \theta^\prime)$ for some $\theta^\prime$ depending on the choice of chart.

So if we were to work in a curved space, be it a pseudo-Riemannian spacetime or a 2-dimensional spacial surface (thought of as position in 3D space with some constraint imposed upon it), how would we generalize the usual definition of the center of mass to work in the presence of curvature?

Comment: The formula isn't summing points but relative distance vectors weighed by the values of a density function. For the sake of students we aren't teaching the difference between affine space (house numbers) and spatial vectors very thoroughly, but that doesn't mean that we don't understand them. It was taught to me in high school, so it may depend on the school system if this is part of the syllabus or not.  If you need a proper mathematical definition that is strict about these physical terms, there are enough books like "Analysis, Manifolds and Physics" by Choquet-Bruhat for that purpose.

Comment: Did you notice that it's a weighted sum, the weight being the mass of the each point.

Comment: @CuriousOne I understand that there is pedagogical simplification in the usual definition. And the culture-wide realization of the importance of distinguishing affine space and the tangent spaces is a relatively recent one. Anyway, I'm just curious about what a proper definition looks like.

Comment: @ABcDexter I'm not sure what you mean. Of course the summation is a weighted sum, and the integral by its nature is a generalized weighted sum. What I'm wondering about isn't the weights, but about the summing of the "vectors" involved.

Comment: I deleted an exchange involving some inappropriate comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your volume element changes to $\sqrt{-\det g}d^nx$ if the metric $g$ is not flat. That is:

$$\bar x^µ=\frac{\int \rho(x)x^\mu\sqrt{-\det g}d^nx}{\int \rho(x)\sqrt{-\det g}d^nx}$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll work through this and see if it makes full sense to me. Am I to take det g to mean the matrix M such that given two vectors v and u, I would write u^t M v to compute their inner product? (And so in standard coordinates, would be just the identity matrix. Although that doesn't account for the negative sign, so perhaps you're also assuming a negative piece to the signature).

Comment: The minus sign come in the non-Euclidean case (general relativity) to compensate for the signature.

The metric is not exactly a matrix, but it behaves similarly. Search term for your search engine: metric tensor.

$$\langle x, y\rangle = g(x,y)=g_{\mu\nu}x^\mu y^\nu$$

Comment: Right. I know the metric is an (0,2)tensor. However, the determinant is defined for linear operators, strictly speaking. But I think the interpretation I wrote out sounds consistent.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, the determinant is taken from a matrix which you get, if you write down the components of the metric tensor. In terms of transformation properties it is strictly speaking not a matrix, but you can still compute the determinant in the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that center of mass is meaningless in presence of curvature. The notion of COM arises precisely due to the fact that flat spacetime (where these sums are perfectly well defined) posseses high degree of symmetry. In this case we are interested in translational symmetry. This leads to conservation of total momentum, which means that dynamics of the center of mass separates in equations from internal dynamics of the system. Nothing like that is possible in curved spacetime.

It might be still possible to define (in much more complicated way) a quantity which has some (but not all) properties of center of mass and is meaningful on manifolds or some other nice spaces. But with no translational invariance it will not be relevant or useful concept.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep your reply in mind as I think about the limitations of the other answer I got involving the metric tensor. I'm sure without translational symmetries, many important properties go out the door quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Tic-Tacs,

There are actually quite a few questions rolled up in what you have said/asked -I'll try to answer the ones that I can.

First off, in more rigorous physics texts, your equation:

$$\frac{\sum m_k r_k}{\sum m_k}$$

is more properly spelled out as:

$$\frac{\sum m_k \vec{r}_k}{\sum m_k}$$

so the way I see it, we aren't summing points in the first place -- we're summing vectors, and you have already stated that summing vectors is an okay-thing.  A similar line of reasoning applies to the integral over density that you mentioned.

Next, in physics (or anything else), there's nothing wrong with the *coordinates* of the center of mass of an object being dependent on the coordinate system.  This is just like your latitude and longitude being dependent on where you draw the equator and the prime meridian.  There is only a problem if you are standing on a different continent when you re-define your equator, etc.

Likewise, if you draw a yellow dot on an object at its center of mass, you don't have to erase/move the yellow dot around on the object if you change your coordinate system.  You merely changed the coordinates of that same yellow dot relative to the origin.

Adding all this up, the notion of center of mass doesn't show any bias towards a coordinate system (curved, rectilinear, or otherwise), because you don't have to move the "yellow dot" around.

So, yes, center of mass is a meaningful definition in a curved coordinate system.  Lastly, I'm unaware of any "usual" method of defining it - I suppose we are all free to come up with our own as long as it doesn't move the "yellow dot" around to some other location on the object.

Comment: I think, what the OP means is that $\vec{r}$ is not a vector in the transformational sense, it does not transform like a vector would transform (namely with the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation). Geometrically, it is not a tangent vector to the considered manifold.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

As I mentioned in a comment above, how should we define the center of mass with respect to polar coordinates, then? Suppose we have a circle and some masses distributed evenly along it. Then, in polar coordinates, we see each $\vec{r}_k$ as $(r, \theta_k)$ with $r$ fixed. Averaging these coordinates gives us $(r, \theta^\prime)$ for some angle $\theta^\prime$, while the true center of mass should be at $(0, 0)$ by the symmetry of the situation.